# If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$, then for all $\delta>0$, the set $(a-\delta,a+\delta)-\{a\}$ has always an element of the domain of $f$.

Tags: calculus, limits

According to the definition of limit, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ if
$$\text{for all} \ \epsilon >0 \ \text{there is a} \ \delta>0 \ \text{such that for all} \ x, \text{if} \ 0<\lvert x-a\rvert<\delta, \text{then} \ \lvert f(x)-L\rvert<\epsilon$$

I want to know if it is true that if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$, then for all $\delta>0$ there is an $x\in Domf$ (the domain of $f$) such that $0<\lvert x-a\rvert<\delta$. In other words, the set $(a-\delta,a+\delta)-\{a\}$ has always an element of the domain of $f$.

My intuitive approach: We have that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$. Suppose that there is an $\beta>0$ such that the set $(a-\beta,a+\beta)-\{a\}$ has no elements of the domain of $f$. I have understood that it has no sense to write $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ if for an $\epsilon >0$ we can't find some $\delta>0$ such that there is $x\in Domf$ such that $0<\lvert x-a\rvert<\delta$ (is this correct?). Since we can do this (find some $\delta>0$) for every $\epsilon >0$, and for smaller an $\epsilon >0$ we will need also and smaller $\delta>0$ (i can't find a counterexample of this); then, for a sufficiently small $\epsilon >0$ we will need some $\delta>0$ smaller than $\beta$ such that the set $(a-\delta,a+\delta)-\{a\}$ has an element of the domain of $f$, say, $x$. But $x$ would be clearly in $(a-\beta,a+\beta)-\{a\}$, contradiction.

I think that clearly the mistake would be in "for smaller an $\epsilon >0$ we will need also and smaller $\delta>0$", but if not, i can't find the rigorous "math words" to prove it. I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, recall that there is no reason to presume that $a\in \text{Dom} f$. What you want to know is whether we can be sure that elements (distinct from $a$) of $\text{Dom} f$ appear arbitrarily close to $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

> I have understood that it has no sense to write $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ if for an $\epsilon >0$ we can't find some $\delta>0$ such that there is $x\in \text{Dom} f$ such that $0<\lvert x-a\rvert<\delta$. (Is this correct?).

It is correct, but it would be more helpful to write instead:

> I have understood that it has no sense to write $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ if for an $\epsilon >0$ we can't find some $\delta>0$ such that $\{x: 0<\lvert x-a\rvert<\delta\}\;\subset\;  \text{Dom} f$ holds true.

For suppose it has sense. Then for some particular $\epsilon_0$, but for each of the choices $1, 1/2, 1/3, \dots 1/n, \dots$, $\;\;\{x: 0<\lvert x-a\rvert<1/n\}\;\not\subset\;  \text{Dom} f.$ This illustrates that $x$ values failing to be in the domain appear arbitrarily close to $a$. But this is not compatible with the definition, since for all $x$ near enough to $a$ (given $\epsilon=\epsilon_0$), the statement  $$\lvert f(x)-L\rvert<\epsilon_0$$ needs to make sense.

I think your argument falls short because of an example like $f(x)=0,$ continuous everywhere. For a smaller epsilon, you do not need a smaller delta. You can use the same delta for any epsilon.

Comment: Does this make sense to you, user?